# Scrapy with non-blocking RabbitMQ Twisted protocol

Tags: python, scrapy, rabbitmq, twisted

I am trying to get around Scrapy's requirement of feeding the spider with URLs from start_urls array or start_requests generator. Instead, I would like to kick the downloader (and subsequent downloader middlewarew) from a callback that is triggered by RabbigMQ's Twisted protocol whenever it receives a message on a particular exchange.

Following, I have a simple example of a consumer and producer app. The producer app is a Python program that sends URLs to RabbitMQ exchange. The consumer is a non-blocking Twisted protocol that simply prints them to stdout.

Here's the sample consumer Twisted protocol. It listens to routing key urls on exchange quotes:

```py
import pika
from pika import spec
from pika.adapters import twisted_connection
from pika.exchange_type import ExchangeType
from twisted.internet import reactor, protocol, defer
from twisted.internet.defer import inlineCallbacks
from twisted.python import log

PREFETCH_COUNT = 2
EXCHANGE = "quotes"
ROUTING_KEY = "urls"


class PikaProtocol(twisted_connection.TwistedProtocolConnection):
    connected = False
    name = "AMQP:Protocol"

    def __init__(self, factory, parameters):
        super().__init__(parameters)
        self.factory = factory

    @inlineCallbacks
    def connectionReady(self):
        self._channel = yield self.channel()
        yield self._channel.basic_qos(prefetch_count=PREFETCH_COUNT)
        self.connected = True
        yield self._channel.confirm_delivery()
        for (
                exchange,
                routing_key,
                callback,
        ) in self.factory.read_list:
            yield self.setup_read(exchange, routing_key, callback)

        self.send()

    @inlineCallbacks
    def read(self, exchange, routing_key, callback):
        """Add an exchange to the list of exchanges to read from."""
        if self.connected:
            yield self.setup_read(exchange, routing_key, callback)

    @inlineCallbacks
    def setup_read(self, exchange, routing_key, callback):
        """This function does the work to read from an exchange."""
        if exchange:
            yield self._channel.exchange_declare(
                exchange=exchange,
                exchange_type=ExchangeType.topic,
                durable=True,
                auto_delete=False,
            )

        yield self._channel.queue_declare(queue=routing_key, durable=True)
        if exchange:
            yield self._channel.queue_bind(queue=routing_key, exchange=exchange)
            yield self._channel.queue_bind(
                queue=routing_key, exchange=exchange, routing_key=routing_key
            )

        (
            queue,
            _consumer_tag,
        ) = yield self._channel.basic_consume(queue=routing_key, auto_ack=False)
        d = queue.get()
        d.addCallback(self._read_item, queue, callback)
        d.addErrback(self._read_item_err)

    def _read_item(self, item, queue, callback):
        """Callback function which is called when an item is read."""
        d = queue.get()
        d.addCallback(self._read_item, queue, callback)
        d.addErrback(self._read_item_err)
        (
            channel,
            deliver,
            _props,
            msg,
        ) = item

        log.msg(
            "%s (%s): %s" % (deliver.exchange, deliver.routing_key, repr(msg)),
            system="Pika:<=",
        )
        d = defer.maybeDeferred(callback, item)
        d.addCallbacks(
            lambda _: channel.basic_ack(deliver.delivery_tag),
            lambda _: channel.basic_nack(deliver.delivery_tag),
        )

    @staticmethod
    def _read_item_err(error):
        print(error)

    def send(self):
        """If connected, send all waiting messages."""
        if self.connected:
            while self.factory.queued_messages:
                (
                    exchange,
                    r_key,
                    message,
                ) = self.factory.queued_messages.pop(0)
                self.send_message(exchange, r_key, message)

    @inlineCallbacks
    def send_message(self, exchange, routing_key, msg):
        """Send a single message."""
        log.msg("%s (%s): %s" % (exchange, routing_key, repr(msg)), system="Pika:=>")
        yield self._channel.exchange_declare(
            exchange=exchange,
            exchange_type=ExchangeType.topic,
            durable=True,
            auto_delete=False,
        )
        prop = spec.BasicProperties(delivery_mode=2)
        try:
            yield self._channel.basic_publish(
                exchange=exchange, routing_key=routing_key, body=msg, properties=prop
            )
        except Exception as error:  # pylint: disable=W0703
            log.msg("Error while sending message: %s" % error, system=self.name)


class PikaFactory(protocol.ReconnectingClientFactory):
    name = "AMQP:Factory"

    def __init__(self, parameters):
        self.parameters = parameters
        self.client = None
        self.queued_messages = []
        self.read_list = []

    def startedConnecting(self, connector):
        log.msg("Started to connect.", system=self.name)

    def buildProtocol(self, addr):
        self.resetDelay()
        log.msg("Connected", system=self.name)
        self.client = PikaProtocol(self, self.parameters)
        return self.client

    def clientConnectionLost(self, connector, reason):  # pylint: disable=W0221
        log.msg("Lost connection.  Reason: %s" % reason.value, system=self.name)
        protocol.ReconnectingClientFactory.clientConnectionLost(self, connector, reason)

    def clientConnectionFailed(self, connector, reason):
        log.msg("Connection failed. Reason: %s" % reason.value, system=self.name)
        protocol.ReconnectingClientFactory.clientConnectionFailed(
            self, connector, reason
        )

    def send_message(self, exchange=None, routing_key=None, message=None):
        self.queued_messages.append((exchange, routing_key, message))
        if self.client is not None:
            self.client.send()

    def read_messages(self, exchange, routing_key, callback):
        """Configure an exchange to be read from."""
        self.read_list.append((exchange, routing_key, callback))
        if self.client is not None:
            self.client.read(exchange, routing_key, callback)



def main():
    parameters = pika.ConnectionParameters(
        host="localhost",
        virtual_host="/",
        credentials=pika.PlainCredentials("guest", "guest"),
    )

    def callback(tup):
        url = tup[-1].decode('utf-8')
        print(f'Received {url}')

    f = PikaFactory(parameters)
    f.read_messages(EXCHANGE, ROUTING_KEY, callback)

    reactor.connectTCP(parameters._host, parameters._port, f)

    reactor.run()
    

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Here is how you would feed URLs to it (and see them printed on stdout):

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python
import pika

connection = pika.BlockingConnection(
    pika.ConnectionParameters(host='localhost'))
channel = connection.channel()

channel.basic_publish(exchange='quotes', routing_key='urls', body='http://quotes.toscrape.com/page/1/')
print(" [x] Sent url to quotes exchange")
connection.close()
```

How do I run the quotes spider downloader (instead of simply printing the URLs to stdout)?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

it might help you, I struggled and I finally managed to let my spider consume rabbitmq through the TwistedAdapter

```
class TwistedConsumer(scrapy.Spider):
""" Twisted compatible RabbitMQ Consumer
"""

start_urls = []

def start_consuming(self):

    self.channel = None
    self.exchange = None
    self.queue = None
    self.queue_object = None
    self.consumer_tag = None

    
    self.user = get_project_settings().get('RABBITMQ_USER') 
    self.password = get_project_settings().get('RABBITMQ_PASSWORD')
    self.host = get_project_settings().get('RABBITMQ_HOST')
    self.port = get_project_settings().get('RABBITMQ_PORT')
    self.virtual_host = get_project_settings().get('RABBITMQ_VIRTUAL_HOST')
    self.queue = get_project_settings().get('RABBITMQ_QUEUE_NAME')
    self.exchange = get_project_settings().get('RABBITMQ_EXCHANGE')
    self.routing_key = get_project_settings().get('RABBITMQ_ROUTING_KEY')
    
    credentials = pika.PlainCredentials(self.user, self.password)
    parameters = pika.ConnectionParameters(self.host,
                                            self.port,
                                            self.virtual_host,
                                            credentials,
                                            heartbeat=10)
    

    # a deffered of a connection
    cc = protocol.ClientCreator(
        reactor,
        twisted_connection.TwistedProtocolConnection,
        parameters
    )
    
    
    self.deferedConnection = cc.connectTCP(self.host, self.port)
    
    
    self.deferedConnection.addCallback(lambda protocol: protocol.ready)
    
    
    self.deferedConnection.addCallback(self.run)
    
    
    self.deferedConnection.addCallback(self.populate_start_urls)
    
    self.crawler.signals.connect(self.spider_idle, signal=signals.spider_idle)
    self.crawler.signals.connect(self.item_scraped, signal=signals.item_scraped)
    

def populate_start_urls(self):
    self.start_urls = [self.queue_object.get()]
    
    
def spider_idle(self):
    """ Waits for request to be scheduled.
    :return: None
    """
    raise DontCloseSpider


def item_scraped(self, *args, **kwargs):
    self.logger.info(f"Item scraped")
    


@defer.inlineCallbacks
def run(self, connection):
    """Receives the connection as parameter and then consumes from the queue
    periodically.
    """
    self.channel = yield connection.channel()

    yield self.channel.exchange_declare(exchange=self.exchange,
                                            auto_delete=True,
                                            exchange_type="direct",
                                            durable=True)

    yield self.channel.queue_declare(queue=self.queue,
                                        durable=True,
                                        arguments={
                                            ... # put whatever arg you may need
                                        })

    self.channel.queue_bind(exchange=self.exchange,
                            routing_key=self.routing_key,
                            queue=self.queue)

    yield self.channel.basic_qos(prefetch_count=10)

    self.queue_object, self.consumer_tag = yield self.channel.basic_consume(
                                                            queue=self.queue,
                                                            auto_ack=True)

    l = task.LoopingCall(self.read, self.queue_object)
    l.start(interval=0.01)
    
    
def next_request(body):
    raise NotImplementedError
    
    
@defer.inlineCallbacks
def read(self, queue_object):
    """Responsible for consuming the queue. See that it ACKs at the end.
    """

    # queue_object.get() is a ClosableDeferredQueue, hence, a Deferred
    ch, method, properties, body = yield queue_object.get()

    if body:
        self.next_request(body)
```

And then implement a spider inheriting from it :

```
class MySpider(TwistedConsumer):
name = "my_spider"

start_urls = []


@classmethod
def from_crawler(cls, crawler):
    
    spider = super(MySpider, cls).from_crawler(crawler)
    spider.start_consuming()
    return spider


def next_request(self, body):
    
    # parse your body here
    # ....
    # let's assume your url is coming from the body
    
    request = scrapy.Request(url, callback=self.parse)    
    self.crawler.engine.crawl(request, self)


def parse(self, response):
   # do your parsing stuff here
```